resource missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration
i've got these 2 warnings when I apply a file with deployment & service. I've verified but i use the same namespace: test, and ConfigMap named : nginx-config
what can be wrong ?
But my pods is working ok.
1
Warning: resource deployments/nginx is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
deployment.apps/nginx configured

2
Warning: resource services/nginx is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.

mycode:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: test
data:
  nginx.conf: '
events {
}
http {
   server {
       listen 80;
       location / {
           return 200 "Hello world 2024!";
       }
   }
}
'
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
      #- image: registry.gitlab.peruprop.com/root/freetest:1.0
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-vol
            mountPath: /etc/nginx/
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: nginx-config
            items:
              - key: nginx.conf
                path: nginx.conf
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
  namespace: test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 80-80
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP


You can safely ignore those warning. They just mean that you used kubectl apply instead of kubectl create for creating objects in Kubernetes which is totally fine.
Usually kubectl apply is used to update the objects but it also can be used to create them.
You can read more about kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#how-to-create-objects

Is there any way to remove the warning?
